First science fiction story with music causing behavioral changes
This question of mine prompts me to wonder what the first SF story with music deliberately or inadvertently affecting human behavior for a scientific reason (no magical musical spells). I can think of examples back to the 1940s (Nothing But Gingerbread Left) but there's probably a precursor to that.

This is more an extended comment than a definitive answer, but there are some interesting examples older than the 1940s in science fiction. A possibly ambiguous example can be found in the Roman de Troie (12th century), and a much clearer example in the short story The Piper of Dreams by James Huneker (1902).
As for the Roman de Troie, the Wikipedia article on the history of science fiction mentions the story of the "Chambre des Beautés":

The Roman de Troie, another twelfth-century work, features the famous
Chambre de Beautes, which contained four automata, one of which held a
magic mirror, one of which performed somersaults, one of which played
musical instruments, and one which showed people what they most
needed.

The musical automaton plays music affecting people beyond what is natural. Here’s an excerpt from the translation by Burguess and Kelly (2017), p.223:

The statue played them so sweetly that neither the music of the
spheres nor the heavenly choirs were so delightful to hear. All this
seemed otherworldly. When those in the Chamber took counsel, whether
they were asleep or awake, it played such a sweet tune that whoever
heard it felt no pain or sorrow as long as they were able to hear or
listen to it. No one there was seized with foolish impulses, evil
thoughts or mad desires. It had very beneficial effects on its
audiences, for they could speak in quite a loud voice and no one could
hear what they said. This was very much to the liking of those who
spoke of love, secret matters and other topics to which they did not
want others to be privy.

However, in this story, the automata are moved by "necromancy", and the word "automata" neither appears in the original text, nor in the translation by Burguess and Kelly. So one could argue that this isn't really through scientific or technological means. On the other hand, several academic publications do describe these statues as "automata"–including the introduction of the Burguess and Kelly's translation. So I guess the scifi or proto-scifi nature of this story might be up to debate, though I suspect it would require a good knowledge of Old French and medieval literature/culture to discuss the issue. (For those interested digging deeper in this specific subject, Elly Truitt discusses automata in French medieval literature in her 2004 article ‘Trei poëte, sages dotors, qui mout sorent di nigromance’: Knowledge and Automata in Twelfth-Century French Literature).
Besides the Roman de Troie, the oldest example I could find was the 1902 short story The Piper of Dreams, by James Huneker. The story is about a music composer, Illowski, who creates music influencing people up to the point of rioting and threatening social order. At first, there’s no scientific explanation of the phenomenon, but then this is elucidated in a discussion between three characters, Lenyard, Scheff, and Neveshka. Neveshka says (bold's mine):

 "If Illowski's discovery—which is based on the great natural laws of
 heat, light, gravitation, electricity—if this discovery were placed in
 the hands of fools, the world would perish. Music has been so long the
 plaything of sensuality, the theatre for idle men and women, that its
 real greatness is forgotten. In Illowski's hands it is a moral force.
 He comes to destroy that he may rebuild. He accomplishes it with the
 raw elements themselves. Remember—'I hear the grinding of the swords,
 and He shall come—!'" Neshevna made a nervous gesture and disappeared
 through a door near the tall desk covered with music-paper—the desk
 whereon Illowski plotted the ruin of civilization.

Then, Scheff, addressing to Lenyard (bold's mine):

 "Now since you have seen the dread laboratory, don't hang around that
 desk; there's nothing there you can understand. The music-paper is
 covered with electrical and chemical formulæ, not notes. I've seen
 them. Lenyard, let's go back to Paris and dine, like sensible
 men,—which we are not. [...]

Scheff continues (bold's mine):

 "I don't know what he has written recently," was the sullen answer,
 "but if the newspapers are to be believed, he is crazy. Music all
 color, no rhythm, no themes, and then his preaching of Nietzsche—it's
 all wrong, all wrong, my boy. Art was made for joy. When it is
 anything else, it's a dangerous explosive. Chemically separate certain
 natural elements and they rush together with a thunder-clap. That's
 what Illowski has done. It isn't art. It's science—the science of
 dangerous sounds. He discovered that sound-vibrations rule the
 universe, that they may be turned into a musical Roentgen ray. He
 presents this in a condensed art, an electric form—"

And:

 "The means? Why, dear boy, he just hypnotizes people,
 and promises them bank accounts and angel-wings. That's how he does
 the trick. Here's the tramcar. Jump in. I'm dying of thirst. To the
 Monferino!" ...


More generally, the idea of music controlling behavior through technology or scientifically explainable means has existed since at least Mesmer in the 18th century or Charcot in the 19th century (Huneker's The Piper of Dreams does mention Charcot), with a revival in the middle of the 20th century due to the Cold War.
You can find an interesting account of that in Musical Hypnosis: Sound and Selfhood from Mesmerism to Brainwashing by James Kennaway. This is where I found the existence of Huneker's The Piper of Dreams. Note that Kennaway does not claim that Huneker's short story is the oldest instance of this idea in science fiction; it wouldn't be surprising if there are older examples, as this idea was in the zeitgeist long before 1902.
